How to configure /readiness and /liveness probes correctly in Spring Boot?
I am configuring my Spring Boot 3.0.2 application with this setting:
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
Calling /actuator/health I am getting the following result:
"livenessState": {
    "status": "UP"
},
"readinessState": {
    "status": "UP"
}

And calling /actuator/health/liveness will return:
{
  "status": "Up"
}

If I change my configuration to management.health.livenessstate.enabled=true only I can call the /actuator/health endpoint and the liveness probe is included in the result:
"livenessState": {
    "status": "UP"
}

But if I call /actuator/health/liveness I am getting a 404 - Not Found error.
Why can the liveness endpoint not called with the second configuration option? And what is the suggested configuration to enable the liveness probe?

/actuator/health works without any config. I believe it's best to get an overview over Spring Actuator by having a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/actuator/enabling.html
